# Javascript functionality regarding filter function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code(s), which is code typed and executed in the console, while in a breakpoint, the following returns 0:

```
$(target).children().filter(function(el){
    return $(el).attr("standard" == '')
}).length
```

The following return true:

```
$($(target).children()[0]).attr("standard") == ''
```

Why does the first code block not return a count/length of 1, as the first item of the collection satisfies the filter functions's delegate?

Comment: Typo in `.attr("standard" == '')` in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a misplaced bracket. Update from

```
$(el).attr("standard" == '')
```

to

```
$(el).attr("standard") == ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(target).children().filter(function(el){return $(el).attr("standard" == '')}).length
```

This does not return 1 because `.attr("standard")` returns the value associated with that attribute. You cannot perform calculations/comparisons inside it. You have to take the attribute value in a separate variable and then compare.

Or just fix your typo

```
attr("standard") == ''
```

Comment: "*You cannot perform calculations/comparisions inside it*" sure you could as OP already does. It's just incorrect, since you aren't looking up the correct thing now.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally forgot the bracket, which was actually part of the code, but I fixed it now:

This did not work:

```
$(target).children().filter(function(el){ return $(el).attr("standard") == '' }).length
```

This does:

```
$(target).children().filter(function(){ return $(this).attr("standard") == '' }).length
```

And so does:

```
$(target).children().filter(function(i,el){ return $(el).attr("standard") == '' }).length
```

The problem was that the delegates first parameter automatically referred to the index and not to the JQuery element

Comment: Which should be obvious from looking up the API for jQuery, as that's a very long standing thing that has always been inconsistent with the general pattern JS iterator methods keep to.